# undefined symbols on qml extension (from example)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to adapt a simple example from qt (Using qt creator 3.5.1, from qt 5.5.1) to create a new qml type. Here's the trivial new type:

```
class Person : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(int shoeSize READ shoeSize WRITE setShoeSize)
public:
    Person(QObject *parent = 0): QObject(parent), m_shoeSize(0) {}

    QString name() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(const QString & name) { m_name = name; }

    int shoeSize() const { return m_shoeSize; }
    void setShoeSize(int s) { m_shoeSize = s; }

private:
    QString m_name;
    int m_shoeSize;
};
```

When I try to register it:

```
qmlRegisterType<Person>("People", 1,0, "Person");
```

I get

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "Person::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)", referenced
>   from:
>         vtable for QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement in main.o   "Person::qt_metacast(char const*)", referenced from: ...

I think I need to add a "library" to the .pro file, but I'm at a loss.
Any ideas?

I already have the following:

```
QT += core qml quick widgets
```

Comment: Do you have an implementation for you `Person` class? Did you add it into the project file (.pro)?

Comment: The implementation is given with the declaration above. I put the whole class definition in the "main.cpp" that otherwise works just fine. (I.e., before I tried to add the qml extension type, the qt project is producing what I want.)

Comment: Try including the generated moc file `#include "main.moc" ` or put the Person class in a separate file.

Comment: Putting in separate .h/.cpp files fixed the problem.  I did not expect that.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by tpr: The example had Person in a separate .h/.cpp file. When I did that, the program successfully compiled.
Did *not* expect that.